# How to access mongoose validation error outside of callbacks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, error-handling

I have a website with an `index > routes > endpoints > core` structure where endpoints handle request and response and use core modules for database interaction.
Right now, a find function from the core module looks like this:

```
function findUser(data){
   return User.findOne(data)
}
```

From there, my endpoints are able to handle the query data without callbacks. However, I have a `createUser` action that uses schema-level authentication to return an error when the username is not unique. I am not sure how I would return the error from a core module function.

```
function createUser(data){
   var user = new User(data);
   if(//error validation here){
      return //however to return error
   }else{
      user.save();
      return "Success!"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var user = new User(data);
```

you could actualy use

```
function createUser(data){
    return User.create(data);
}
```

this way the `createUser` function returns promise just like the `findUser` function. The `User.create` function calls `save()` automatically.

So you can use it like

```
createUser(userdata)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
```

Comment: I understand I can do that, but I want to keep all database callbacks in my core modules rather than dealing with them in endpoints.